# Laravel 8 User profile not showing even the buttons or alt image

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, web

I'm trying to view/change profile image of a user but I can't seem to do it right thus nothing is being displayed as I just started to create a page using Laravel. I can see other tutorials have profile image in their profile page but when it comes to me this is the only thing being displayed [what it looks like][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/00nyo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUs8d.png) even though I haven't done anything of the code in the profile.

I tried changing the `**APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000**` and `***php artisan storage:link***` and removing the comment of the features in `**jetstream**` and nothing seems to work
Below is the code of the profile photo, what should I do or fix? I'm not really good yet in using Laravel framework

```
   <x-slot name="form">
        <!-- Profile Photo -->
        @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
            <div x-data="{photoName: null, photoPreview: null}" class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                <!-- Profile Photo File Input -->
                <input type="file"
                            wire:model="photo"
                            x-ref="photo"
                            x-on:change="
                                    photoName = $refs.photo.files[0].name;
                                    const reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                                        photoPreview = e.target.result;
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL($refs.photo.files[0]);
                            " />

                <x-jet-label for="photo" value="{{ __('Photo') }}" />

                <!-- Current Profile Photo -->
                <div class="mt-2" x-show="! photoPreview">
                    <img src="{{ $this->user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $this->user->name }}" class="rounded-full h-20 w-20 object-cover">
                </div>

                <!-- New Profile Photo Preview -->
                <div class="mt-2" x-show="photoPreview" style="display: none;">
                    <span class="block rounded-full w-20 h-20 bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center"
                          x-bind:style="'background-image: url(\'' + photoPreview + '\');'">
                    </span>
                </div>

                <x-jet-secondary-button class="mt-2 mr-2" type="button" x-on:click.prevent="$refs.photo.click()">
                    {{ __('Select A New Photo') }}
                </x-jet-secondary-button>

                @if ($this->user->profile_photo_path)
                    <x-jet-secondary-button type="button" class="mt-2" wire:click="deleteProfilePhoto">
                        {{ __('Remove Photo') }}
                    </x-jet-secondary-button>
                @endif

                <x-jet-input-error for="photo" class="mt-2" />
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: What is the values of `$this->user->profile_photo_url`?

Comment: It's newly created so none, but as I can see in other YT vids divs or images/alt is displayed such as the button in selecting a new image but those buttons are not displaying so I can't select or insert a new image. That's why I'm confused why the buttons of selecting a new Image is not being displayed

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't activated the profilePhotos section in the configuration of jetstream.

Go to config/jetstream.php and find the features section. You will probably see that the Features::profilePhotos() is commented.

Comment: The profile photos are usually here:  https://your.domain/storage/profile-photos/xyz.png, and the php artisan storage:link creates the symlink for that.  In jetstream config:  Features::profilePhotos().  See if the profile image is even being rendered, and if so, what the src evaluates to.  You might also try deleting the symlink and recreating it.

Comment: I did activate the **Features::profilePhotos(),** and the result is the same, no image or alt is being displayed and buttons for selecting a new Image, which I think should be displayed as I can see it from other tutorials, but those buttons are not being displayed.

Comment: Is the config cached? If so, please run php artisan config:clear in order to see whether that will bring a change